# HFS+ vs APFS: What are the pros/cons of converting HDDs to APFS?

Tags: filesystem, hfs+, hdd, high-sierra, apfs

I've got a few USB 3.0 HDDs I use for backup and game storage, all formatted in HFS+.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of migrating to APFS on an HDD?

Comment: I suppose this might depend on what steps you take to migrate an HDD to APFS. Do you have a specific macOS version and procedure in mind?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## APFS (Apple File System) compared to HFS+

Almost all differences apply to Solid State Drives (SSD) and Hard Disk Drives (HDD) as well, while users of HDDs may not see an improvement in speed.

### APFS disadvantages/drawbacks

- [Incompatible with macOS 10.12 Sierra and earlier](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208018) (including OS X)
- Windows drivers/tools to read/write APFS disks are not available (as of today)
- Currently not supported by Fusion Drives/HDDs (coming soon)
- [**Boot Camp** doesn't read from or write to APFS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208018)-formatted volumes
- **[No AFP support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208018)**: Volumes formatted as APFS can't offer share points over the network using AFP.
- Any [Time Machine share points must be shared over SMB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208018) instead of AFP.
- **Directory Hard links** are not supported
- [File names cannot contain unassigned codepoints in the Unicode 9.0 standard](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016999-CH6-DontLinkElementID_3)

### APFS advantages

- [Faster disk speed in general on SSDs](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=macOS-APFS-HFS-Benchmarks)
- Almost instant file and directory duplication
- Increased maximum number of files
- Space sharing
- Better crash protection
- Better date resolution: nanosecond timestamps
- Support for dates beyond February 6, 2040
- [Sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) support
- Larger max. number of files (2^63 vs 2^32)
- Supports [Copy-on-Write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) (replaces journaling)

See also Apple's [APFS Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide) and the Wikipedia's [Apple_File_System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System).

Comment: I think the bit about hard links is not entirely correct: as far as I know, APFS does not support directory hard links, but it does support regular file hard links.

Comment: Hm, isn't APFS completely unsupported on OS X but with limited support on macOS up until 10.12.5 – except being the boot volume for 10.12? 10.12.6 then breaking some stuff (https://eclecticlight.co/2017/07/24/sierra-isnt-finished-yet-apfs-support-is-undone-in-10-12-6/)

Comment: @LangLangC At least not officially: "For example, a USB storage device formatted as APFS can be read by a Mac using High Sierra, but not by a Mac using Sierra or earlier." (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208018)

Comment: According to https://bombich.com/blog/2019/09/12/analysis-apfs-enumeration-performance-on-rotational-hard-drives, it seems that "Enumerating an APFS filesystem on a traditional HDD (rotational disk) will take 3-20X longer than HFS+ on the same hardware."